# ffmpeg errors out with Error initializing output stream 0:0 for the setting `-profile:v main`

Tags: video, ffmpeg

We are using ffmpeg for generating HSL streaming files (.m3u8, .ts) from multiple type of input video and audio like avi, mp4, mp3, mkv, m4a etc. We are trying to encode everything into h264 streams to support modern browsers. But we are facing issues in converting few videos of type avi and mp4 (not all). Below is the ffmpeg command (it's using ffmpeg fluent on NodeJS).

```js
ffmpeg(fileName)
  .outputOptions([
    '-c:v h264',
    '-profile:v main',
    `-vf scale=1280:-2`,
    '-hls_list_size 0',
    '-start_number 0',
    '-hls_time 10',
    '-loglevel error',
  ])
  .output(output_file_path)
```

When we try to run this with some set of specific avi and mp4 samples, it errors out saying
`Error: ffmpeg exited with code 1: Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height`.

I tried changing few commands (like providing crf value) and tried to run them, The only time it successfully converted converted them was when I removed the output option `-profile:v main`. I am not sure about the reason behind it.

I ran ffprobe to get the information from the videos that were not able to generate streams. I have them uploaded to gist here: https://gist.github.com/vishwasnavadak/91b5c978e2a3cb7a7c7a2bb505487263

Is there something I am missing? What is the reason for it to error out when `-profile:v main` option is present?

Comment: in javascript ` will work along side with single quotes. And yes they still error out on cli. The answered question does the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `-pix_fmt yuv420p`. Your inputs are getting converted to `yuv444p` which isn't acceptable for H.264 Main profile.